# Jquery ajax issue, keep getting undefined as a result value

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm a total newbie at using ajax and jquery's ajax wrapper function. Trying to get json from an API and append the result to the html of a site that I'm building.

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'api/v1/get_profesors.php',
    success : function(data){                                           
        var content = 'Name : '+data.name ;
        content += ' Surname : '+data.surname ;
        content += ' Bio : '+data.bio ;
        content += ' Instrument : '+data.instrument ;
        $("#profesori").append(content);
    }
});
```

The result which I'm getting is *Name : undefined Surname : undefined Bio : undefined Instrument : undefined*.

Oh, and here's part of the JSON which I'm receiving from the API:

```
{"id":7,"name":"adsssss","surname":"THERE I GO","bio":"Jupi","instrument":"Gitara","img":null}{"id":8,"name":"Andrija","surname":"Profesor","bio":null,"instrument":null,"img":null}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few things you have to keep in mind while doing this type of stuff :**

**1.** As suggested by [Shubham Khatri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri). Check the API response by using `console.log(data)` in the `ajax` success call.

**2.** Response you are getting from the api is wrong. It should be either `array of objects` or `object of arrays`.

**Wrong :**

```
var data = {"id":7,"name":"adsssss","surname":"THERE I GO","bio":"Jupi","instrument":"Gitara","img":null}{"id":8,"name":"Andrija","surname":"Profesor","bio":null,"instrument":null,"img":null}
```

**Correction :**

```
var data = [
             {"id":7,"name":"adsssss","surname":"THERE I GO","bio":"Jupi","instrument":"Gitara","img":null},
             {"id":8,"name":"Andrija","surname":"Profesor","bio":null,"instrument":null,"img":null} 
           ];
```

**3.** In your `ajax` success function you have to `loop` the `data array` as it is having two objects in it.

```
for (var i in data) {
  console.log('Name : '+data[i].name);
}
```

**Output :**

```
Name : adsssss
Name : Andrija
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you get the JSON as a response from the API by using `console.log(data)` in the `ajax` success call.

Then you need to parse the received JSON using `JSON.parse()`

```
 $.ajax({
     type : 'GET',
     url : 'api/v1/get_profesors.php',
     success : function(data){
         var data = JSON.parse(data);
         var content = 'Name : '+data.name ;
         content += ' Surname : '+data.surname ;
         content += ' Bio : '+data.bio ;
         content += ' Instrument : '+data.instrument ;
         $("#profesori").append(content);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `data[0].name` etc for your response.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14352113)

Comment: @indramurari that you for your critique

Answer (score 0):

Please use datatype in ajax as  dataType: "json", please see example below.

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: hb_base_url + "consumer",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            first_name: $("#namec").val(),
            last_name: $("#surnamec").val(),
            email: $("#emailc").val(),
            mobile: $("#numberc").val(),
            password: $("#passwordc").val()
        }),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
});